# Proof of Conditional Expectation using Indicator Random Variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am not able to understand the proof of below

$$\mathbb{E}[X|A] = \frac{1}{P[A]}\mathbb{E}[X\cdot\mathbb{I_A}]$$

Specifically, some books imply that $$X=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\cdot\mathbb{I}_{X=k}$$

Can you please explain the meaning of above statement?

Comment: If X is supported on non negative integers, then it's true

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{E}[X\mid A]$?  In particular, many authors take $\frac1{\mathbb{P}(A)}\mathbb{E}[X1_A]$ as the definition of $\mathbb{E}[X\mid A]$ for a non-null event $A$.

Comment: Conditional Expectation. I was looking for a mathematical proof for the same.

Comment: That doesn't answer it.  Let me phrase it differently: What is your definition of "conditional expectation" (of $X$ conditioned on a non-null event $A$, denoted) $\mathbb{E}[X\mid A]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $X = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty k \cdot \mathbb{I}_{X = k}$ makes use of the fact that the indicator variable $\mathbb{I}_{X = k}$ is defined to equal 1 when $X = k$, and 0 otherwise. So as long as $X$ is guaranteed to take some non-negative integer value, all we're doing is writing a convoluted form of it - it's the sum of a whole bunch of zero values, plus for some value $k$ it's equal to $k \times 1$.